# Python override abstractmethod property setter and getter using decorators only

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, abstract

I'm trying to create an abstract class that would force the implementation to implement both a getter and a setter. I'm following what is described at https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty but I keep getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    test = B('bar')
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class B with abstract methods foo
```

even though I implement both `foo` getter and setter in B.

Here is my code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

    @foo.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self, val):
        pass

    def do_stuff(self):
        print(self.foo)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._foo = val

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo

    @A.foo.setter
    def foo(self, val):
        self._foo = val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = B('bar')
    test.do_stuff()
    test.foo = 'barr'
    test.do_stuff()
```

I know there is a way to do this by defining the property without using the decorator, like so

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def _get_foo(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _set_foo(self, val):
        pass

    def do_stuff(self):
        print(self.foo)

    foo = property(_get_foo, _set_foo)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._foo = val

    def _get_foo(self):
        return self._foo

    def _set_foo(self, val):
        self._foo = val

    foo = property(_get_foo, _set_foo)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = B('bar')
    test.do_stuff()
    test.foo = 'barr'
    test.do_stuff()
```

While this does work, there surely must be a way to do that with just the decorators, no?

I'm running python 3.4.

Comment: There are 2 separate problems here: The bug in your code (you used `@A.foo.setter` instead of `@foo.setter`), and creating an abstract setter. As far as I know, the `abc` module can't force your child classes to implement *writeable* properties. If possible, reduce your question to just one of those two problems.

Comment: Oh, it can't? That's too bad, sounds like defining property without decorators is the way to do then.

Comment: @HotCoffee: why do you want to use abstract methods? Unlike java, in python one uses duck typing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code raises an exception because you're using the `A.foo.setter` decorator on the `B.foo` method, so the `B.foo` method does not actually implement the abstract method `A.foo` with the same signature.

Remove the `A.` specification from the decorator, and your code would work:

```
@foo.setter
def foo(self, val):
    self._foo = val
```

With the fix, you'll find that the class `A` does enforce that the child classes implement both the getter and the setter for `foo` (the exception you saw was actually a result of you not implementing the setter).

Comment: The python doc page I referenced uses `@C.x.setter`, so I followed the example. I guess the doc is wrong then. Btw, while this removes the error, it doesn't force the subclass to implement the setter, which is the whole point of using the abstract methods in the first case. If I comment out the setter in `B` and its usage in `__main__`, the code runs without any error, but I want it to complain that the abstract setter was not implemented by `B`.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue11610) you would need to go over an additional class in the hierarchy that implements solely the getter. The setter would then stay with the concrete class:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

    @foo.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self, val):
        pass

    def do_stuff(self):
        print(self.foo)

class B(A):

    _foo = None

    @A.foo.getter
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo

class C(B):

    def __init__(self, val):
        self._foo = val

    @B.foo.setter
    def foo(self, val):
        self._foo = val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = C('bar')
    test.do_stuff()
    test.foo = 'barr'
    test.do_stuff()
```

If you remove either the getter in B or the setter in C you will get the desired `TypeError` exception.

This solution, however, forces you to put the definitions of getter and setter in two different classes, which might be impractical in real applications.